# optimize if else condition in jquery

Tags: jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#submit").click(function(){

         var userinput = $('#username').val();
         var mobilenumber=$('#mobnum').val();
         var address1=$('#addr1').val();
         var address2=$('#addr2').val();

         var characterReg = /^([a-zA-Z]{2,30})$/;
         var numericReg=/^\d*[0-9](|.\d*[0-9]|,\d*[0-9])?$/;
         var emailReg=/^([\w-\.]+@([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]{2,4})?$/;
         var addrReg = /^\s*[a-zA-Z0-9,\s]+\s*$/;

         var errors=false;

        if(!characterReg.test(userinput)){
             $('#username').addClass('box');
             $('.alert').show();
            errors=true;
        }else{
            $('#username').removeClass('box');
             $('.alert').hide();
        }
        if(!numericReg.test(mobilenumber)){
            $('#mobnum').addClass('box');
             $('.alert').show();
            errors=true;
        }else{
            $('#mobnum').removeClass('box');
             $('.alert').hide();
        }
        if($('#mail').val()==''){
            $('#mail').addClass('box');
             $('.alert').show();
            errors=true;
        }else{
            $('#mail').removeClass('box');
            $('.alert').hide();
        }
        if($('#pwd').val()==''){
            $('#pwd').addClass('box');
             $('.alert').show();
            errors=true;    
        }else{
            $('#pwd').removeClass('box');
            $('.alert').hide();
        }
        if(!addrReg.test(address1)){
            $('#addr1').addClass('box');
             $('.alert').show();
            errors=true;
        }else{
            $('#addr1').removeClass('box');
            $('.alert').hide();
        }
        if(!characterReg.test(address2)){
            $('#addr2').addClass('box');
             $('.alert').show();
            errors=true;    
        }else{
            $('#addr2').removeClass('box');
            $('.alert').hide();
        }
        if(errors){
            return false;
        }else{
            return true;
        }
    }); });
```

hello all ... i have posted this question 2 days before but i dint get any solution.... please anyone help me......how to optimize this code.. i tried with switch case but i couldn't get correct output...and i don't know how to deal with multiple id's in for each loop... is there any other way to optimize this code???

Answer (score 1):

You can create a validate function which accepts element and regex format for validation.

Also, you can use `toggle()` instead of `show()`/`hide()` and `toggleClass()` instead of `addClass()`/`removeClass()`

```
function validate(element, regex)
{
   var errors = !regex.test($(element).val() || $(element).val()=='')
   $(element).toggleClass('box',errors);
   $('.alert').toggle(errors )
}
```

OR with your approach,

```
function validate(element, regex)
{
   if(!regex.test($(element).val() ) || $(element).val()=='')
   {
        $(element).addClass('box');
        $('.alert').show();
        errors=true;
   }else{
        $(element).removeClass('box');
        $('.alert').hide();
   }

 return error;
}
```

and use it as follows,

```
validate('#username', '/^([a-zA-Z]{2,30})$/');
validate('#mobnum', '/^\d*[0-9](|.\d*[0-9]|,\d*[0-9])?$/');
```

Comment: $(element).toggleClass('box',errors);      here can i add more than one element?

Comment: in your case it will be the element in the question. I don't see you can use multiple elements in this case as you need to call validate() per element validation.

Comment: @moksha can you please try second alternative.

Comment: @moksha Can you please try updated second alternative. I have updated if condition.